# Why does this accordion stops working when placed inside ngFor

Tags: angular

Trying to make this accordion work in component template it works when it is outside the ngFor but doesn't expand when it is inside

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles;">
            <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

It works when it is outside ngFor the moment I place it inside it stops working as the accordion does not open. Btw ngFor works in my case it repeats the section.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("activee");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
  }
```

css

```
/* Accor */
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .activee, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }

  .accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  .activee:after {
    content: "\2212";
  }

  .panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
```

Comment: Don't try to mix DOM manipulation using javascript with angular. please

Comment: I know but is it because of that or there is another reason.

Comment: @zuyi try not doing that and see if it persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to maintain a state for each article as

```
articles: any[] = [  //it could have other properties like article text etc.
    { id: 1, visible: true },
    { id: 2, visible: true },
    { id: 3, visible: true },
    { id: 4, visible: true },
    { id: 5, visible: true }
];
```

and toggle that state as

```
(click)="article.visible = !article.visible"
```

which you can use to control the presence of the element as

```
*ngIf="article.visible"
```

or use conditional class binding as

```
[class.visible]="article.visible"
```

A working example present at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysmaxp